# javascript dom rewrite is not working for text align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function testit(){
document.getElementById("th1").style.textAlign = "right";
}
```

```css
#th1{
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr><center><th colspan="2" id="th1">EmergencyImportantContactsnumbers</th><center></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="2" id="th1" >Emergency.SQUCampus</tr></tr>
   <tr><th>Emergency.m1</th><th id="th1" >Emergency.m2</th><tr>
   <tr><td>Emergency.m3</td><td id="th1" >Emergency.m4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Emergency.m5</td><td id="th1" >Emergency.m6</td></tr>
   
   </table>
<button onclick="testit();">Text Script</button>
```

I want to change the text align of cell in table. i have used javascript for changing the text align. When i re edit the style code it is not working.

I want to change th1 text alignment to right. But my code is not working.
Please help me thank u.

Comment: id must be unique, use class instead

Comment: make your id as class.

Comment: Make ID unique and `th` should be immediate child of `tr` instead of `<tr><center><th`.

Comment: Relevant question: [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: So, if you comment your CSS code, its working. Which means, CSS is overriding your JS code. May be, it could be the order in which CSS and JS are loaded??

Comment: You do not need a <center> tag there. Also noticed your ID reference is duplicated.

Comment: @Luke class also not working.

Comment: @CodeLღver class also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<table>
         <tr><center><th colspan="2" class="th1">EmergencyImportantContactsnumbers</th><center></tr>
         <tr><th colspan="2" class="th1" >Emergency.SQUCampus</tr></tr>
         <tr><th>Emergency.m1</th><th class="th1" >Emergency.m2</th><tr>
         <tr><td>Emergency.m3</td><td class="th1" >Emergency.m4</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Emergency.m5</td><td class="th1" >Emergency.m6</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Use classes instead of id.

CSS:

```
table{
  width: 400px;
}
.th1{
  text-align:left;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS:

```
var th1 = document.getElementsByClassName("th1");
for (var i = 0; i < th1.length; i += 1) {
    th1[i].style.textAlign = "right";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to `<center>` tag. Secondly, IDs are unique and hence you need to use class. And lastly, since you have tagged `JQuery`, you can use `css()` to assign the CSS to the elements once the DOM is ready:

```js
/*$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".th1").css({
    'text-align': 'right'
  });
});
*/

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("th1");
for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].style.textAlign = 'right';
}
```

```css
.th1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="th1">EmergencyImportantContactsnumbers</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="th1">Emergency.SQUCampus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Emergency.m1</th>
    <th id="th1">Emergency.m2</th>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Emergency.m3</td>
        <td id="th1">Emergency.m4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Emergency.m5</td>
        <td id="th1">Emergency.m6</td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

**Update:**
Added JavaScript code too and commented JQuery code.

Comment: You want it in JavaScript? Why have you tagged JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
 <style>
    #th1{
    text-align:left;
    }
    .th2{
    text-align:right !important;

    }
    </style>

    <table>
         <tr><center><th colspan="2" id="th1">EmergencyImportantContactsnumbers</th><center></tr>
         <tr><th colspan="2" id="th1" >Emergency.SQUCampus</tr></tr>
         <tr><th>Emergency.m1</th><th id="th1" >Emergency.m2</th><tr>
         <tr><td>Emergency.m3</td><td id="th1" >Emergency.m4</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Emergency.m5</td><td id="th1" >Emergency.m6</td></tr>   
     </table>
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $('table #th1 ').addClass("th2");
      });
     </script>
```